# How to check if a CNContact is a "me contact" in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cncontactstore

I want to be able to identify if the contact I am trying to edit is "Me contact" as part of my swift code. 
i see we have [this func](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contacts/cncontactstore/1402987-unifiedmecontactwithkeys) to modify it for Mac OS. Is there a way I can do that for my iOS app using Swift

Comment: thats only for macOS 10.11+ .. :( not for iOS